# How can I run PHPUnit with CakePHP tests without the Cake console?

Tags: cakephp, gruntjs, phpunit, cakephp-2.5

I want to automate CakePHP tests with Grunt, and found `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-phpunit');`, which can automate PHPUnit, but I'm sure it can't handle `cake test`.

I'm also satisfied with a solution that runs `cake test` from Grunt, but I'm really interested in a way to run the PHPUnit command, which can execute CakePHP tests.

**Edit:** I'm using the current stable release of CakePHP, which is 2.5.4 now.

Comment: You need to post the *exact* CakePHP version. It differs between 2 and 3.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I meant the current stable. I edit my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

On a [Japanese site](http://php-tips.com/2012/01/23/cakephp2-0-phpunit-on-netbeans/) I found an interesting idea:

First I had to duplicate `webroot/test.php` as `webroot/phpunit.php`, and replace the last line:

```
--- a/webroot/test.php
+++ b/webroot/phpunit-bootstrap.php
@@ -86,4 +86,4 @@ if (Configure::read('debug') < 1) {

 require_once CAKE . 'TestSuite' . DS . 'CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php';

-CakeTestSuiteDispatcher::run();
+App::load('CakeTestSuiteCommand');
```

This makes it possible to use this as a bootstrap for PHPUnit.

Then you can create a `phpunit.xml` to ease the testing process.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit colors="true" stopOnFailure="false" bootstrap="webroot/phpunit-bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="AllTests">
            <directory suffix=".php">Test/Case</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Now I only need to add `grunt-phpunit` config to my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
phpunit: {
    options: {
        bin: 'phpunit',
        configuration: 'phpunit.xml',
        colors: true,
    },
    app: {
        options: {
            testsuite: 'AllTests',
        },
    },
}
```

Now if I run `grunt phpunit`, (or configure `grunt watch` to run the `phpunit` task upon changes, and change a file) PHPUnit runs my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that grunt-phpunit expects a default a standard phpunit execution, if that's true you can't run it that way and you will have to adept this tool. I guess it is parsing the test output. CakePHP2 doesn't let you simply run "phpunit" like you can with CakePHP now and other libs. CakePHP2 extends the phpunit test classes so I doubt you can run them without using the cakephp test shell.

We use Jenkins and our own custom made scripts to automate tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm quite disappointed, because FuelPHP also uses its own test cases, but it has a `bootstrap_phpunit.php` that takes care of this. I'm sure CakePHP also has something analogous to that, but if I can't find any, I'll just accept your answer.